# XML selection of parents based on child and or grandchild

Tags: xml, xpath, tree

I'm searching for an XPath string (for VBA Excel) that can look for all nodes on a specific level and that are only returned in case they have a specific (grand) child node. Regardless how 'deep' this is nested. Relationale: I don't know how deep a specific child is nested therefore I can't make a fixed path.

In case of the example below. I'm searching for all nodes that are directly under the root '' and which have any child that contain the name 'Test'

XML STRING:

```
<Program>
   <AA name="1"/>
   <BB name="2">
      <CC name="Test"/>
   </BB>
   <DD name="Test"/>
   <EE name="3">
      <FF name="4">
         <GG name="Test"/>
      </FF>
   </EE>
</Program>
```

REQUIRED SELECTION:

```
Item(0) = <BB name="2">
Item(1) = <DD name="Test">
Item(2) = <EE name="3">
```

The following XPath expression gives the nodes under `Program`

```
xmlDoc.selectNodes("/Program/*")
```

The following XPath expression gives the nodes which contain the name `Test`

```
xmlDoc.selectNodes("//*[@name="Test"]")
```

**What I need is not a 'union' of the 2 paths but a 'overlap'. Does anybody know how to make this?**

Comment: Is this what you want? `xmlDoc.selectNodes("/Program/*[//@name='Test']")`

Comment: Nope, this will result in an union. But thanks for your quick response

Comment: Sorry, I meant `xmlDoc.selectNodes("/Program/*[.//@name='Test']")`  ;)

Comment: Tom, thats it :-) Briliant now I can continue with the rest :-)

Comment: @LudoHouben If Tom's post answers your question, then mark it as the answer.

Comment: Sorry CaBieberach. I'm new here so just did your request :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following XPath expression selects what you need:

```
/Program/*[.//@name='Test']
```

It fetches all immediate children of `Program` and then selects the ones that have a `name` attribute value of `'Test'` or contain descendants that do.

A more verbose and perhaps more readable version of this expression would be:

```
 /Program/*[descendant-or-self::*/attribute::name='Test']
```

So your VBA code can look like this:

```
mlDoc.selectNodes("/Program/*[descendant-or-self::*/attribute::name='Test']")
```